# Benefits of using Realm Listview over standard React Native Listview

Tags: react-native, realm

The Realm documentation recommends using their implementation of ListView:

```
import { ListView } from 'realm/react-native';
```

But I can't find any info on what the actual difference is and what the benefits are.

Also with new react native versions coming out every other week won't it risk getting outdated pretty fast?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When used with Realm collections (i.e. `List` or `Results`), the Realm `ListView` is designed to be more CPU/memory efficient than the stock `ListView`. It also will help prevent common pitfalls by automatically using static snapshots of the collections, which is necessary since Realm collections can change at any time. So we recommend using it for preventing certain classes of bugs, as well as for the performance benefit.

I will update the documentation with some of this information. We're actively monitoring for any possible breaking changes in the React Native repo, but it's designed to (hopefully) not break for most kinds of changes to the stock `ListView`.

Comment: Thank you, that was just what I was looking for :)

Comment: @Scott Kyle thanks for the useful answer. Was the documentation updated as you mentioned?

Comment: Is the Realm `ListView` still recommended now that ReactNative has [FlatList](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/blog/2017/03/13/better-list-views.html)